# a (probably trivial) question on trace theory

Tags: functional-analysis

I was going through the trace theorem on Sobolev space which speaks of its existence for function $\in W^{k,p}(\Omega)$. My question is whether the trace operator unique if it exists?. My intuitive answer is no. I need a justification even if I am wrong.

Comment: Under normal conventions it **is** unique. What you normally do, is to require that the trace operator $T$ satisfies $T f = f|_{\partial \Omega}$ for $f \in V := C^\infty (\overline{\Omega})$ (or some slightly different class $V$). The proof will then consist in showing (or already knowing) that this class $V$ of functions is dense and in showing that the operator $T$ is bounded on $V$. It then extends **uniquely** (requiring it to be continuous) to the closure $\overline{V}$, which will equal $W^{k,p}$ if the domain is sensible (and only in theses cases, the trace is normally constructed).

Comment: Thank you. Could grasp it well.

Comment: PhoemueX...Another question is - Why in the proof of the trace theorem in L.C.Evans' book on PDE, he has considered functions in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)\bigcap C(\overline{\Omega})$ when it is enough to choose functions in $W^{1,p}$, which tackles a bigger issue?.